# How to make two array value in same frequency with minimum swap cost

Tags: java, data-structures

Example is

input-

```
 A: 1 2 2
 B: 1 3 3
```

after swap-

```
A: 1 3 2
B: 1 2 3
```

swap cost- min of Ai and Bi

here is 2 answer.

input-

```
 A: 1 2
 B: 4 5
```

not possbilbe then result 0

input-

```
A: 1 2 2 2
B: 1 2 3 3
```

after swap-

```
A: 1 2 3 2
B: 1 2 2 3
```

I am tried in this way.But not working properly.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SWap {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=0;
    if(sc.hasNext())
        t=sc.nextInt();
    while(t-->0){
        ArrayList<Long> a=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Long> b=new ArrayList<>();
    int n=0;
    if(sc.hasNext())
        n=sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
           long n1=0;
            if(sc.hasNext())
               n1=sc.nextLong();
            a.add(n1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
           long n2=0;
            if(sc.hasNext())
               n2=sc.nextLong();
            b.add(n2);
        }
        Collections.sort(a);
        Collections.sort(b);
        int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++){
            if(!b.contains(a.get(i))){
                long no=a.get(i);
                a.remove(i);
                a.add(b.get(i));
                b.remove(i);
                b.add(no);
                long min=Math.min(a.get(i),b.get(i));
                count+=min;
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(a);
        Collections.sort(b);
        if(a.equals(b))
            System.out.println(count);
        else
            System.out.println("-1");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please elaborate the example as i don't understand on what condition you want to swap the data ? or you just want to interchange alternate elements ?

Comment: just i want make two array identical  .if i sort them after swap arrays will be identical.

Comment: okay let me tell you my understanding from this examples...from example 1. You have swapped second element of A & B. so i can see only 1 swap not 2. For example 2. why there is no swap is it because the numbers are sorted ? for example 3. you only swapped 3rd element ? i want to understand the condition on which you want the swap and is there any limit for swapping ?

Comment: swap may not in same index. my purpose is to make array identical . swap cost should be minimum. for each swap the  swap cost should  min of Ai and Bj.

Answer (score 0):

try swapping using the least element in 2 arrays many times if it costs less .

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please review your answer and go a little bit more into detail and maybe add some example (e.g. code)? Thanks